# How do I run C/C++ applications on Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, dalvik

How do I compile and run applications written in C/C++ and under NDK on Android OS??

Does the application compile and run in Dalvik or ART?
Or independent is that VM??

In the case of programs written in other languages, how is it?
For example (C# in Xamarin) or (Delphi in Firemonkey) or (Basic) or (Python)? Thanks a lot for my questions and answers.

Comment: do some googling, show your efforts.......

Comment: you need to expand your question bit few parts of the question are confusing. also add little explanation about your research it will make others easy to understand in which direction you are going.

Answer (score 0):

**Please, do some research.**

Basically yes, almost all non native solutions use some kind of VMs. For example Xamarin use **MonoVM** for Android platform. The C# code is compiled into CIL, which is executed by the Mono execution environment. This execution environment is run side by side with the Java Virtual Machine, which means the applications are not executed the same as a native application, however, they are executed in an equivalent way. This means that the performance is tied to MonoVMs implementation.

**MonoVM** is packaged with the application, which means that Xamarin Platform applications can be installed in the same way as a native application, without any additional installs.